# request.POST not reading form data in django

Tags: python, django

I have my views file:

```py
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Note
# Create your views here.

def index(request): 
    return render(request, "index.html", {})

def write(request): 
    notes = Note.objects 
    return render(request, "write.html", {})

def create(request): 
    if request.POST: 

        body = request.POST['note']
        title = request.POST['title']

        print(f'title = { title }\nbody = { body }'
```

and my html code:

```html
<h1>CREATE A NOTE</h1>

<form action="{% url 'notes:create' %}" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}

    <label for="title">Title</label>
    <input type="text" name="title"><br> 
    <label for="note">Note</label>
    <input type="text" name="note"><br>

    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Whenever I submit this form and try to access either the title or note values I get a MultiValueDictKeyError

Comment: also post your urls.py

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `MultiValueDictKeyError` comes when you try to access something from `request.POST` which doesn't exist. It's basically the same the python `KeyError`. Use `request.POST.get('key', 'default_if_key_doesn't exist')`

```py
def create(request): 
    if request.POST: 
        body = request.POST.get('note', '')
        title = request.POST('title', '')

        print(f'title = { title }\nbody = { body }'
```

Comment: Shouldn't those values exist when we submit the filled out form?

Comment: Yes. I suppose you hadn't filled out one of the things. Add the `required` attribute to your `input`s, but use the `.get` method anyway. It's safer. But doesn't it solve your problem?

Comment: I think I was being an idiot and not renavigating to the page. I was only refreshing it and I don't think my browser was serving me my updated html.

Comment: It's not idiotic, I do it all the time . But can you accept my answer if it works? I suggest you do this, else if a person changes the `name` of an input and submits the form, a 500 error would occur.